# smallest value, smallest date, smallest time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Transaction":["ett852741963", "ett123654789", "ett753951852", "ett159753852"],
                "Arrival Scan":["02-11-2021 23:45:21", "", "05-11-2021 06:12:10", "04-11-2021 08:19:36"],
                  "Unloading Scan":["", "03-11-2021 06:14:22", "03-11-2021 11:41:22", "04-11-2021 14:45:21"],
                  "Unpacking Scan":["", "03-11-2021 8:02:11", "02-11-2021 15:01:02", ""],
                  "Delivery Scan":["04-11-2021 08:32:10", "", "03-11-2021 17:45:16", ""]})


df

    Transaction        Arrival Scan       Unloading Scan       Unpacking Scan        Delivery Scan
0   ett852741963  02-11-2021 23:45:21                                             04-11-2021 08:32:10
1   ett123654789                       03-11-2021 06:14:22  03-11-2021 8:02:11  
2   ett753951852  05-11-2021 06:12:10  03-11-2021 11:41:22  02-11-2021 15:01:02   03-11-2021 17:45:16
3   ett159753852  04-11-2021 08:19:36  04-11-2021 14:45:21
```

I want to take the first time scan for each transaction based on Arrival Scan to Delivery Scan and display it in the First Time column

so that later the dataframe becomes

```
    Transaction       Arrival Scan        Unloading Scan      Unpacking Scan        Delivery Scan         First Time
0   ett852741963  02-11-2021 23:45:21                                            04-11-2021 08:32:10  02-11-2021 23:45:21
1   ett123654789                       03-11-2021 06:14:22  03-11-2021 8:02:11                        03-11-2021 06:14:22    
                                       
2   ett753951852  05-11-2021 06:12:10  03-11-2021 11:41:22  02-11-2021 15:01:02  03-11-2021 17:45:16  02-11-2021 15:01:02
3   ett159753852  04-11-2021 08:19:36  04-11-2021 14:45:21                                            04-11-2021 08:19:36
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can `replace` your empty string with `nan`, then `bfill` and `iloc` to get the first valid values:

```
df['First Time'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].replace("", np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
```

On another note, you should treat your datetime data as datetime, then, with your data structure, you can simply use `min`:

```
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)

df['First Time'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].min(axis=1)
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the script 'df['First Time'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].replace("", np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]' . see, Transaction ett753951852 should be First Time 02-11-2021 15:01:02 not 05-11-2021 06:12:10

Comment: Oh unpacking scan is earlier than arrival scan? Then you definitely want to use the second approach.

Comment: Yes, First Time must read the earliest time of each Scan.
If the condition is like that, then what is the script?

Comment: Like I said, it's the second approach. Your date format is really inconvenient to compare as strings...